# Returning an async generator from LLMChain LangChain for Streaming

Tags: python, langchain, azure-openai

I am working on a FastAPI application that should stream tokens from a GPT-4 model deployed on Azure. I'm using the AzureChatOpenAI and LLMChain from Langchain for API access to my models which are deployed in Azure.

I tried to use the `astream` method of the LLMChain object. I'm really at a loss for why this isn't working, as I only see streaming on my terminal. I expected the `astream` method to return an async generator so that I could stream each token as they are generated by the model, instead I am getting the final string as a response.

I think that the behavior I am seeing might be due to the `StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler`.

Below is a code snippet (just a part of it, enough for debugging):

```
class OpenAIModel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.llm = None

    def __call__(self, #params) -> str:

        if self.llm is None:
            openai_params = {
                # other params removed for debugging purpose
                'streaming': streaming,
                'callback_manager': AsyncCallbackManager([StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()]) if streaming else None,
                'verbose': True if streaming else False
            }

            self.llm = AzureChatOpenAI(**openai_params)

        return self

    async def streaming_answer(self, question: str):
        qaPrompt = PromptTemplate(
            input_variables=["question"], template="OPENAI_TEMPLATE"  # Anonymized template
        )

        chain = LLMChain(llm=self.llm, prompt=qaPrompt)

        async for chunk in chain.astream({"question": question}):
            yield chunk
```

Comment: Did you get this solved?